# How to speed up UTF-8 string processing

Tags: string, rust

I am parsing tab-separated values:

```
pub fn parse_tsv(line: &str) -> MyType {
    for (i, value) in line.split('\t').enumerate() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

`perf` top contains `str.find`. When I look in the generated assembly code, there is much work related to UTF-8 coding of the symbols in `&str`.

And it is relatively veeeery slow. It takes 99% of the execution time.

But to find `\t` I can't simply search for one-byte `\t` in a UTF-8 string.

What am I doing wrong? What is Rust stdlib doing wrong?

Or maybe in Rust there is a some string library which can represent strings simply by 'u8' bytes? But with all the `split()`, `find()`, and other methods?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations on? (`--release` with cargo)

Comment: @huon of course

Comment: What's the speed difference if you use `"\t"` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as your string is ASCII or you don't need to match on UTF-8 scalars (e.g. like in your case, where you search for tabs), you can just treat it as bytes with the `as_bytes()` method and afterwards operate on `u8` characters (bytes) instead of `char`s (UTF-8 scalars). This should be much faster. With `&[u8]`, which is a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html), you can still use methods applicable to `&str` slices like `split()`, `find()`, etc.

```
let line = String::new();
let bytes = line.as_bytes();

pub fn parse_tsv(line: &[u8]) {
    for (i, value) in line.split(|c| *c == b'\t').enumerate() {

    }
}

fn main() {
    let line = String::new();
    let bytes = line.as_bytes();

    parse_tsv(&bytes)
}
```

Comment: wow, I can use split on `&[u8]`, i didn't know about this, thanks!